# how to apply mootools morph effect to more than one div?

Tags: javascript, mootools, html

I am having trouble applying the morph effect of mootools to more than one div. i want that all div morphs at the same time, but instead just the first one morphs. Please help!Thank you if you are taking your time to look at this!
i have got the code from that page: http://davidwalsh.name/morphing-elements-mootools-css
but i have two divs instead of one, that are exactly the same ( class, id etc are the same)!
cheers Timm

Answer (score 0):

you need Fx.Elements from mootools-more:

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Elements

which is better due to the unified timer etc.

the david walsh example is set for multiple elements also so not sure what you are doing wrong. in any case, its much easier to do:

```
$$("div.foo").morph({ width: 300, opacity: [0,1], background: "#ffffff"});
```

which will morph all these properties on all divs with a class of foo.

Comment: i see, i dont get over the multiple elements problem however. might be related to them having the same ids? i put this down here, maybe this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/HeUrV/15/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/HeUrV/23/ - and yes, you cannot have more than 1 element with the same id, its malformed html. ids are meant to be unique. in this example i have grouped it by class...